# Custom loading MediaWiki skinScripts

Tags: mediawiki

I'm about to set up some custom JS and CSS using something like this in `LocalSettings.php`, from here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Snippets/Load_an_additional_JavaScript_or_stylesheet_file_on_all_pages#Code

```php
$wgResourceModules['zzz.customizations'] = array(
    'styles' => "skin.css", // Stylesheet to be loaded in all skins
    // Custom styles to apply only to Vector skin. Remove if you don't use it
    'skinStyles' => array(
        'vector' => 'skin-vector.css',
    ),
    // End custom styles for vector
    'scripts' => "skin.js", // Script file to be loaded in all skins
    'localBasePath' => "$IP/customizations/",
    'remoteBasePath' => "$wgScriptPath/customizations/"
);

function efCustomBeforePageDisplay( &$out, &$skin ) {
    $out->addModules( array( 'zzz.customizations' ) );
}
```

This code shows a custom CSS that's loaded only for the vector skin, and another that's always loaded. I want to do the same with with the JavaScript, that is, load a JS file that's only for the vector skin as well as one that is always loaded.

I see from that documentation (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceModules) that `skinScripts` is supported, but I don't know how it would fit into the above code. Could anyone show me how to modify the above code to make that happen?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceModules) you linked says:

> **skinScripts**
>   Scripts to include in specific skin contexts.
>   Array keyed by skin name containing file path string or array of file path strings.

That isn't much different from the `skinStyles` entry, so I'd assume that something like this would work:

```php
$wgResourceModules['zzz.customizations'] = array(
    'styles' => "skin.css", // Stylesheet to be loaded in all skins
    // Custom styles to apply only to Vector skin. Remove if you don't use it
    'skinStyles' => array(
        'vector' => 'skin-vector.css',
    ),
    // End custom styles for vector
    'scripts' => "skin.js", // Script file to be loaded in all skins
    'skinScripts' => array(
        'vector' => 'skin-vector.js',
    ),
    'localBasePath' => "$IP/customizations/",
    'remoteBasePath' => "$wgScriptPath/customizations/"
);

function efCustomBeforePageDisplay( &$out, &$skin ) {
    $out->addModules( array( 'zzz.customizations' ) );
}
```

Where `vector` is the name of the skin, and `skin-vector.js` is the JavaScript file that only goes with that skin.